# Regex to filter out "n" occurence of character

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, validation

I need a regular expression (for input validation) that filters out all the special characters except "underscore", so all the characters in range [a-zA-Z0-9\underscore] are allowed and can occur more than once. But in my expression I cannot have 2 consecutive occurrences of "underscore" and also my string cannot start with "_".

Comment: filter out? did you mean replace those that dont match the criteria

Comment: can you pls provide a list of valid and invalid inputs?

Comment: No, I don't have to replace. I will only accept as input for an input field all the characters in range [a-zA-Z0-9\underscore] but I cannot accept input strings starting with underscore or having two consecutive occurrences of underscore. But strings ending with a single occurrence of underscore are ok.

Comment: Why not simply filter twice? `value.replace(/\W/g, "").replace(/^_|_(?=_)/g,"")`

Comment: For instance valid input can be: "Hello012_" or "_hello09_Hello" but not "__Hello" or not"hello__77Hello"

Comment: I cannot do operations with code. I have to define a regex string to capture the behaviour and put it as argument of ng-pattern, that is: ng-pattern ="my regex" where ng-pattern is an Angular Js provided directive.

Comment: I'm confused. In the question you say _"also my string cannot start with `"_"`"_, but then you go on say that `"_hello09_Hello"` is valid. Why is that valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9]_?)+$/
```

One or more... alphanumeric chars optionally followed by a single underscore

[image: Regexplained]

Comment: Could simplify slightly to `/^(?:[a-z\d]_?)+$/i`

Comment: @Phrogz I am not sure that is simpler, it might be better, but I think more complex to understand. What do you think about this alternative... `^(?:[^_\W]_?)+$`?

Comment: I agree that your original is more directly understandable. Your proposed variation I consider excellently amusing and clever, but would not recommend it. :)

Comment: This solution features catastrophic backtracking as much as the deleted answer :-(

Comment: @Bergi that's true. Your answer is like a correct version of my answer, although, I think you need to anchor it, as @phrogz points out... `/^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:_(?:[A-Za-z0-9]*))*$/`

Comment: @BillyMoon: I'm not sure, OP said he used in Angular; I'm not sure about its anchoring rules. Might be…

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use [groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) so that the [repetitions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) work properly:

```
/[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:_(?:[A-Za-z0-9]+|$))*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you will find that inverting your logic—finding any problem, rather than ensuring there are no problems—yields a simpler solution:

```js
// starts with underscore
// or has two underscores in a row
// or has a character other than alpha/numeric/underscore
var bad = /^_|_{2}|\W/;
if (bad.test(input)) myInputIsIllegal();
```